# Jasmine: How to expect promise handler to not throw exception

Tags: javascript, jasmine, es6-promise

I have this function:

```
reload() {
    myService.queryData()
        .done(...)
        .always(() => throw "fake exception"); //just to simulate the failure
}
```

I want my test reload function and make sure it does not throw exception nor the promise callback does.

```
describe("reload", function () {
    it("does not throw exception", function (done) {

        spyOn(myService, "queryData").and.callFake(() => {
            let deffered = $.deffered();
            setTimeOut(() => deffered.reject(), 0)
            return deffered.promise();
        });

        reload();
        setTimeout(() => {
           //this is evaluated after the exception has been thrown, but
           //how to check whether exception has been thrown
        }, 2);
    });
});
```

EDIT: I might not be able to return a promise in some cases, where the return type of the function is already defined, e.g component's lifecycle event:

```
MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.load(
            galleryService.nodes().then(galleryResult => this.setState({ nodes: galleryResult.nodes }))
        );
        this.load(
            galleryService.caches().then(cachesResult => this.setState({ caches: cachesResult.caches }))
        );
    }
}

var myComponent = React.createElement(MyComponent);
TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(myComponent); //this triggers the componentDidMount event and I need to make sure it won't throw error.
```

Comment: can't you use `Promise.all` or `Promise.race` to coordinate the flow in your edit snippet?

Comment: I could, but componentDidMount is defined by the framework (REACT) as function that returns void and I don't call it directly. It's called by the framework, when I execute `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(...)`. I was hoping I can isolate the problem to vanilla javascript, but I've failed to formulate the problem correctly...

Comment: I still don't see why you cannot either return a `Promise.all` containing all your promises from `componentDidMount` or factor out the relevant code into a separate, testable function that you call from `componentDidMount`.

Comment: I can and I will when I wont have other choice, but it's not BDD. My expected behaviour is "when user visits page, relevant data are loaded and rendered without unexpected errors". Ideally I want to write tests such way, that they won't fail when I change implementation. I can unit test the extracted function, but it does not cover my original intention. Better than nothing though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that spying on `window.onerror` is the way to go:

```
describe("reload", function () {
    it("does not throw an exception", function (done) {

            spyOn(window, 'onerror').and.callFake((error: any, e: any) => {
                fail(error);
            });

            spyOn(myService, "queryData").and.callFake(() => {
               let deffered = $.deffered();
               setTimeout(deffered.reject, 0);
               return deffered.promise();
           });
        });
        setTimeout(done, 2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Let `reload` return the promise it creates. In your test case, attach a `catch` handler to it which triggers a test failure:

```
reload().catch(err => done.fail(err));
```

**Update after question was edited:** If you cannot change the return value of your original function then factor out the relevant parts into separate functions. For example:

```
function reloadNodes() {
    return somePromise();
}

function reloadCaches() {
    return anotherPromise();
}

function reload() {
    reloadNodes();
    reloadCaches();
}
```

You can then test `reloadNodes` and `reloadCaches` instead of `reload`. Obviously you don't need to create a separate function for each promise, instead combine your promises using something like [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) where appropriate.

Comment: That's the way I did it, but it is not always possible to return an promise, see my edit.

Comment: I will accept this as answer later, since it answers my original question, but it does not actually solve my problem. I admit I described it poorly